# JQuery - Clean Select options on new request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a SELECT object and I'm populating it with AJAX(JQUERY).

```
$("#setor").change(function(){
    $("#loading").css("display", "inline-block");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>quadracontroller/lista_quadras/"+$("#setor").val(),
        success: function(html) {
            $("#quadra").append(html);
            $("#loading").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<select name="quadra" id="quadra">
                                    <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
                                </select>
```

The thing is that for each request it is incrementing the options on the select.

How do I do to clean the  generated on the previous request?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   $("#quadra").empty();
   $("#quadra").append(html);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method destroys the initial "--" option.

Comment: But I can add this: $('#quadra').append('<option value="0">--</option>');

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#quadra').find('option').remove();
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DakUe/)'s a fiddle for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $("#quadra").html(html);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method destroys the initial "--" option.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the initial state upon page load(1) and then restore it before doing `.append()`. Like this:

```
// save the initial HTML
$('#quadra').data('initial-options', $('#quadra').innerHTML);

$("#setor").change(function(){
  $("#loading").css("display", "inline-block");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>quadracontroller/lista_quadras/"+$("#setor").val(),
    success: function(html) {
      var quadra = $("#quadra");

      // restore the initial HTML
      quadra.innerHTML = $('#quadra').data('initial-options');
      quadra.append(html);

      $("#loading").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```